# SSIS XML Source

Tags: xml, xpath, ssis

I have XML Source (WSDL answer) - XML starts with:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Element1 />
    <soap-env:Element2>
        <n0:Response xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
            <Data>
                <item>
                  <Name>Company name</Name>

....
```

and in SSIS in "**Data Flow**", I have "**XML Source**", chose this XML file and generated XSD file - without problems.

Next task is "**Excel destination**" - I connect to the connection manager, choose Sheet1 (where I have prepared name of columns called: 1,2, etc. - without problems.

In mappings I select element "**Name**" like "**Input column**" and "**1**" like "**Destination column**" - without problems.

Everything is fine.

I try run this task and task is successfully complete.
I open my Excel and it's without values, only my headers "1","2" - no changes.. :-(

I tried it the same process with Flat file (.txt) and I got the same result - nothing..

I tried to use "**XML Task**" in "**Control flow**" and using operation "**XPath**" get value from this element (Name) to my testing variable and during run this task I had breakpoint on this XML Task and in "**Watch 1**" I saw right value in my variable - so something is in it..

But I know, that in my XML - WSDL answer - I got value (string) in "Name" element.

So I need values from Name element in Excel destination, but I got nothing.

Comment: You can add a **Data Viewer** in the DFT, between XML Source Adapter and Excel Destination. It will show you what data got into the SSIS pipeline.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky 
Thank for your comment. Yes, I tried also "Data Viewer", but when I have breakpoint on Data flow task and I want to see Data viewer in Data flow, I get nothing again. I expected that I get for example "X rows", but nothing. :-/

Comment: It's really weird that in variable using operation XPath (XML Task) I get right value what I want in my Excel destination.. = value in element "Name" exists..
How is possible that in DFT I get 0 results.. 0 errors, everything seems to be ok.

Comment: It means that the XM is too complicated for the SSIS XML Source Adapter. You can pre-process that XML via XML Task, operation XSLT.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Ok.. I can try it. XSLT I haven't used it yet, so let's start with education. Do you have some recommend what use in XSLT operation in this my case?

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the input XML.